# Android Fotoapparat Camera - Flickering under fluorescent lights

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I've been trying to use Fotoapparat (Java) on my app, but I'm getting random black bars on some devices (flickering, like when you point the camera to a LED display), when the picture is taken under artificial lighting.
I've tried to use the antiBandingMode (all 4 default options: auto, 50hz, 60hz and off) in the camera configuration, but the problem persists.

Funny thing is, this problem does not occur when I'm using the regular camera app on those devices, only when using Fotoapparat in my app.

Sample:

[image]

CameraConfiguration code:

```
private CameraConfiguration cameraConfiguration = CameraConfiguration
            .builder()
            .photoResolution(standardRatio(
                    highestResolution()
            ))
            .focusMode(firstAvailable(
                    continuousFocusPicture(),
                    autoFocus(),
                    fixed()
            ))
            .antiBandingMode(firstAvailable(
                    auto(),
                    hz60(),
                    hz50(),
                    none()
            ))
            .flash(firstAvailable(
                    off()
            ))
            .previewFpsRange(highestFps())
            .sensorSensitivity(highestSensorSensitivity())
            .build();
```

Fotoapparat initializer:

```
private Fotoapparat createFotoapparat() {
        return Fotoapparat
                .with(this)
                .into(cameraView)
                .previewScaleType(ScaleType.CenterInside)
                .lensPosition(back())
                .focusMode(firstAvailable(
                        continuousFocusPicture(),
                        autoFocus(),
                        fixed()
                ))
                .logger(loggers(
                        logcat(),
                        fileLogger(this)
                ))
                .cameraErrorCallback(new CameraErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NotNull CameraException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(PictureActivity.this, getString(R.string.txt_erro_tirar_foto), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
```

Any sugestions to help me handle this problem? I would realy like to keep using Fotoapparat, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I found out that the problem was the sensorSensitivity.
Using .sensorSensitivity(manualSensorSensitivity(500)) I got rid (mostly) of the lines.